# How to clear java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Some one help me how to clear (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException) on below code

```
List<WebElement> elements = dr.findElements(By
                .xpath("//span[@class='small-info']"));
        System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = " + elements.size());
        for (int i = 0; i <= elements.size(); i++) {
            WebElement ele = elements.get(i);
            System.out.println(ele.getText());
            if (ele.getText().contains("chri@en.com")) {
                System.out.println("PASS");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should read :

```
for (int i = 0; i<elements.size(); i++)
```

There is no `elements.size()` index in the List, the last index is `elements.size()-1`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your loop as per below to remove error :

```
       for (int i = 0; i<=elements.size()-1; i++){
            String str = elements.get(i).getText();
             //WebElement ele = elements.get(i);
             //System.out.println(ele.getText());
            System.out.println(str);
             if (str.contains("chri@en.com"))
             {
                 System.out.println("PASS"); 
             }
        }
```

Loop should go till last index so it should be `i<=elements.size()-1`